# Linking between pages in Astro with React

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

I am experimenting using Astro with react.

Astro uses a built in routing system similar to next or remix.

I can't find any kind of `<Link>`component to use like in next or remix.

Am I supposed to integrate react-router to properly route between pages? That somewhat defeats the purpose of their built-in routing system

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely true, Astro as-per the docs uses anchor tags to link to pages. As seen [here](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/), so you can just go ahead in the pages directory and essentially link them together and it should just work!

```
<a href="/about/">
```

Give it a go!